# Laravel form::select correct order

Tags: php, laravel

So i am creating a laravel project. I have seen people using Form::select for a dropdown. but what are the input values? because i see all the information in the selectbox. but i only want to display the column: 'name'

```
  {{ Form::select('tag_id', $tags, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'name']) }}
```

[image]

Comment: `$tags` is supposed to contain the options you want to create. So, if you only want to see names - then make sure that you pass an array that contains only names. (Resp., the name and which key/id value you want it to submit; examples can be found under https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)

Answer (score 0):

If `$tags` is a Collection, you could transform it into the desired result with:

```php
$tags
    ->reduce(
        function ($carry, $t) {
            $carry[$t->id] = $t->name;
            return $carry;
        }, []
    );

/*array (
    1 => 'indoor',
    2 => 'outdoor',
    3 => 'etelage,
    ...
)*/
```

[Drop-Down Lists](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists)